# Dispatch Group not blocking code from running

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I want code within a dispatch group to finish executing before anything else happens, essentially blocking the app from doing anything until this code is done. I can't get the dispatch group to block additional code from running, however. I've tried pretty much every suggestion here on stack, but I don't know what I'm doing want.

My function:

```
- (void)myFunction {

    NSString *myString = @"Hello world";

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    NSLog(@"1 entering the dispatch group");

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self doSomething:myString completion:^{
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
        NSLog(@"2 we have left the dispatch group");
    }];
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"3 notifying that the dispatch group is finished");
    }];
    NSLog(@"4 all process are complete, we are done");
}
```

The output I want via log statements = 1,2,3,4

The output I get via log statements = 1,4,2,3

Why is my code skipping over the dispatch group and print 4 before 2 and 3? Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated. Thank you!

**Update:**

Here is my `doSomething` method. My code keeps hanging on a `dismiss` call.

```
doSomething() {

    viewController.dismiss(animated: false completion: { [weak self] in 
        doMoreCode()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing here actually blocks. `dispatch_group_notify` just says "when the group finishes, run this." The tool you meant to use was `dispatch_group_wait`. If you want 1,2,3,4, then you meant this:

```
- (void)myFunction {

    NSString *myString = @"Hello world";

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    NSLog(@"1 entering the dispatch group");

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self doSomething:myString completion:^{
        NSLog(@"2 we have left the dispatch group");
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"3 notifying that the dispatch group is finished");

    NSLog(@"4 all process are complete, we are done");
}
```

`myFunction` of course cannot be called on the main queue in iOS (since it blocks and you must never block the main queue). And it also must not be called on the same queue that `doSomething:completion:` uses for its completion handler (since that queue will be blocked at `dispatch_group_wait`).

Remember that `dispatch_queue_notify` just adds a block to a queue to be run sometime in the future. So it's a little unclear how you expect 3 and 4 to work (in my example I just collapsed them, but maybe you're looking for something else).

Another approach is to *not* block the application, and just schedule stuff to run when it's supposed to. In that case you can use the main queue. It'd look like this:

```
- (void)myFunction {

    NSString *myString = @"Hello world";

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    NSLog(@"1 entering the dispatch group");

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self doSomething:myString completion:^{
        NSLog(@"2 we have left the dispatch group");
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"3 notifying that the dispatch group is finished");
    });
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"4 all process are complete, we are done");
    });
}
```

Note in both examples, I'm logging 2 before calling `dispatch_group_leave`. In this example, I'm also registering two things to be run on the main queue (in order) after the group is done. In this case, `myFunction` will return immediately (so it can be run on the main queue), but everything should print out in order.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The problem I get with ```dispatch_group_wait``` is that it keeps deadlocking. Any way around this, or just throw a timeout on it?

Comment: I like the use of ```dispatch_group_wait``` because I need to make sure that ```doSomething``` finishes before moving on, but it keeps deadlocking on me. It just hangs, so I'm going to have to investigate why that's happening.

Comment: @user3353890 You deadlock because `dispatch_group_leave` must be called from a different thread than `dispatch_group_wait`. Without knowing what `doSomething` actually does, it's hard to know for sure. Update your question with more details.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the help! I've updated my code. I call ```dispatch_group_leave``` asynchronously, but I keep hanging on a ```dismiss``` viewcontroller call. I'm thinking it might be being called on the wrong thread?

Comment: @rmaddy I think I know what the problem is. ```dismiss``` is being called asynchronously, but the completion block is being called back on the main thread which is currently blocked by ```dispatch wait```, so that's why it's getting deadlocked. I don't know if there's a work around :/

Comment: @user3353890 I would suggest you close this question by accepting which ever answer best helped you with this specific question and then post a new question with relevant code and details about your new issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `doSomething` runs asynchronously, you could wait for the group, but it's generally better to embrace asynchronous patterns, e.g. allow `myFunction` to return immediately, but supply your own completion handler to that method:

```
- (void)myFunctionWithCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
    NSString *myString = @"Hello world";

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    NSLog(@"1 entering the dispatch group");

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self doSomething:myString completion:^{
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
        NSLog(@"2 we have left the dispatch group");
    }];
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"3 notifying that the dispatch group is finished");
    });
}
```

And use it like so:

```
[self myFunctionWithCompletion:^{
    NSLog(@"4 all process are complete, we are done");
}];

// note, it's not done when it gets here, though, because it's asynchronous
```

Clearly, in the above example, the dispatch group is entirely superfluous, but I assume you were doing multiple asynchronous tasks, which is why you introduced the dispatch group. If it really was just this one asynchronous task, you'd just do:

```
- (void)myFunctionWithCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
    NSString *myString = @"Hello world";

    [self doSomething:myString completion:^{
        NSLog(@"The asynchronous doSomething is done");
        completion();
    }];
}
```

Comment: I like the use of multiple notifies and a completion handler. My only problem is I need to ensure that ```doSomething``` finishes before moving on. I'm worried that I'll call ```myFunction``` somewhere, and then code after ```myFunction``` will execute before ```doSomething``` has finished.

Comment: I can understand the appeal of wanting to "ensure `doSomething` finishes before moving on", but I think it's a fundamentally flawed approach. If you look at Apple's APIs, the rule they follow is "if a method can possibly take more than a few milliseconds, make it asynchronous and supply a completion handler". They have, quite correctly in my mind, largely excised their API of any blocking methods. And if you're worried about code "after" `myFunction`, you deal with it like we do all the time with all the other asynchronous APIs we deal with: Put dependent code inside the completion block.

Comment: I hesitate to even suggest it, but the other acceptable pattern is to use promises, a la [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org) or RXPromise. I think it's overkill and it's probably worthwhile to really get comfortable with the "asynchronous method with completion handler" pattern that is an essential iOS programming pattern, before delving into these other patterns, but I mention it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion! I think that is a little bit overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish, but it's interesting to learn about none the less, and good to know that something like that is out there!